# What are custom variables in google analytics how to use them in android app

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics

I am already using custom dimension in google analytics but google analytics dashboard shows custom variables as well. There is no documentation how to create custom variables and how to use them and how they are different from custom dimensions
[image: Following is dashboard image showing custom variables]

Answer (score 1):

Custom Variables exist for backwards compatibility. They have been a feature in previous versions of Google Analytics, and have become deprecated with the introduction of Universal Analytics in 2012. Although the features are not completely equivalent they have been supplanted by custom dimensions.

Since an account may hold data that was collected while custom variables where still a thing Google can't just remove them (lest people loose access to some of their historical data). But to the bet of my knowledge (and yours, apparently) there is no documented way to set custom vars these days.